# Regência de 'tomar a dianteira'

Tags: regência

Usando [linguee.com](https://www.linguee.com) e a [Folha de São Paulo](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ei=k9N9W9-JCZSjmwWKz5LAAg&q=%22tomar+a+dianteira%22+site%3Afolha.uol.com.br%2F&oq=%22tomar+a+dianteira%22+site%3Afolha.uol.com.br%2F&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11327.13609.0.13755.17.17.0.0.0.0.101.1172.14j3.17.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.yY_PLeD3oP8), parece que têm duas alternativas:

> tomar a dianteira de
>   tomar a dianteira em

A segunda aparece mais frequente. As duas preposições são corretas? O sentido que eu quero e o de *tomar iniciativa*.

Comment: linguee não serve para grande coisa....

Comment: @Lambie qual seria uma boa alternativa?

Comment: ANeves Ah, desculpa. Agora peguei. Acho que teria que procurar o que se usa nos jornais.

Comment: tomar a dianteria em [verbo]/tomar a dianteira de [substantivo]